# handling response from callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am calling a `function` with a `callback` inside of a `node` `function`. The `function` fires off and completes its task but I can not figure out how to retrieve the `response` in the `callback` from it.

```
foo() {
  merchant.createCustomerProfile(cardNumber, expDate, email, id, function callback(){
              // How do I retrieve the response from the callback?                   
              // console.log(callback);
            });
     //so I can pass it out here and use it
}
```

The `function` with the `callback` actually `returns` `callback`. it looks like this,

```
function createCustomerProfile(cardNumber, expDate, email, id, callback) {
    ctrl.execute(function(){

        var apiResponse = ctrl.getResponse();

        var response = new ApiContracts.CreateCustomerProfileResponse(apiResponse);
        if(response != null) 
        {
            if(response.getMessages().getResultCode() == ApiContracts.MessageTypeEnum.OK)
            {
                console.log('Successfully created a customer profile with id: ' + response.getCustomerProfileId());
            }
            else
            {
                console.log('Result Code: ' + response.getMessages().getResultCode());
                console.log('Error Code: ' + response.getMessages().getMessage()[0].getCode());
                console.log('Error message: ' + response.getMessages().getMessage()[0].getText());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('Null response received');
        }

        callback(response);
    });
}
```

I am trying to obtain the `resultCode` that should be in the callback function's response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
foo() {
  merchant.createCustomerProfile(cardNumber, expDate, email, id, function callback(response){
              // How do I retrieve the response from the callback?                   
              // console.log(callback);
              console.log(response);
            });
     //so I can pass it out here and use it
}
```